# Check if every element has content inside or wait till it's not JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help to make my example work, I'm new to JS, so please don't trow a tomatoes at me for this:

```
function match_me(element) {
  return element.length > 0;
}

if (document.getElementsByClassName("test-class").every(match_me)) {
  func_1();
} else {
   //Set Interval and check every 100ms till every element
   //length is match, then do "func_1()"
   //or after 100x attempt clear set interval and do "func_2()"
}
```

Basically I want to check if every element on page with class name `test-class` length > 0 (they exist, and have content inside), if this is true, then do `func_1()`, if not wait till they are, if something went wrong (after 100 attempt) just do `func_2()`.

Content to the elements load dynamically when it's requested by user.

Disclaimer: I use `every` in my example just to illustrate my idea.

Can somebody help me to make it work?

Comment: Did you run the above code? So far, it should not work, since `.every` does not work on HTML Collections. Can you please post the entire code and clearly explain what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you want

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(doc) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.test-class').forEach(function(test) {
     if (test && test.innerHTML && test.innerHTML.length) func_1()
     else func_2()`enter code here`
  });
 });
```

It wasn't very clear of the circumstances of when func_1 should be triggered, so keep this in mind

Comment: `It wasn't very clear of the circumstances of when func_1 should be triggered` only if **all** elements in array lenght > 0 (all together), if one, two or all has no content inside then - setInterval ... @BogdanR

Answer (score -2):

You should use:

```
.foreach(match_me(element))
```

on your list of elements.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("test-class")
```

This will use the function `match_me()` on each element.

More documentation here : [forEach](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp).

Comment: You need to convert that `NodeList` to an `array` first of all, then you can use `.forEach` or `.every` on it. like `Array.from( document.getElementsByClassName( 'test' ) ).forEach( .... )`

Comment: NodeList.forEach()
    Executes a provided function once per NodeList element, passing the element as an argument to the function.
From [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)
Am I missing something ? Maybe it doesn't work with `every`, but seems ok with `forEach()`

Comment: Actually, I was going to say `HTMLCollection` which is returned by `.getElementsByClassName()` not `NodeList`. Additionally `NodeList`s doesn't have anything else like `.every()` or `.reduce()`, only `.forEach()`.

Comment: "The getElementsByClassName() method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified class name, as a NodeList object."

From [www.w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName( 'spacer' )` put this in your console and check the type of returned object ( no need for reference ). on the other hand, **w3schools** is not the best resource out there. check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) :)

Comment: I stand corrected, thank you very much. Will not trust w3schools (or any website) blindly again :)