# All elements with class name has html inside JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I make it right:

```
<div class="hit"></div>
<div class="hit"></div>
<div class="hit"></div>
...
```

I have several elements with the same class name `hit`, they are empty by default, but they may become filled with content if the user requested it.

```
<div class="hit"><span id="t1"><p>Some text</p></span></div>
<div class="hit"></div>
<div class="hit"><img alt="" src=""></div>
...
```

I need to check if they all (not just one or two, but all) have content inside, then do a function.

What the best option to use to get the following result:

Note: My example shows only three divs with this class name **but** this is just for the showcase, the real number of divs on the page may vary.

All three has content = `true`;
Only two of three = `false`;
None of three = `false`;

I hope you get the idea.

How it can be done?

I had decided to split my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53762626/check-if-every-element-has-content-inside-or-wait-till-its-not-js) question on several smaller ones (and less complex), this is what I had tried so far:

```
function match(el) {return el.length > 0;}
if (document.getElementsByClassName("hit").every(match)) {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery you could use `:empty` selector like :

```js
if ($('.hit:empty').length > 0) {
  console.log('Not all the divs filled.');
} else {
  alert('All the divs are filled.');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hit"><span id="t1"><p>Some text</p></span></div>
<div class="hit"></div>
<div class="hit"><img alt="" src=""></div>
```

Check every x ms until all the divs are filled :

```js
var checker = setInterval(function() {
  if ($('.hit:empty').length > 0) {
    console.log('Not all the divs filled.');
  } else {
    clearInterval(checker);
  }
}, 1000);

//JSUT FOR TEST PURPOSE
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.hit:empty').html('<b>test</b>');
}, 3000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hit"><span id="t1"><p>Some text</p></span></div>
<div class="hit"></div>
<div class="hit">Image here</div>
```

Max attempts sample :

```js
var counter = 0;
var max_attempts = 3;

var checker = setInterval(function() {
  if ($('.hit:empty').length > 0) {
    console.log('Not all the divs filled.');
  } else {
    clearInterval(checker);
  }

  counter++;
  if (counter === max_attempts) {
    console.log('Max attempts reached');
    clearInterval(checker);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hit"><span id="t1"><p>Some text</p></span></div>
<div class="hit"></div>
<div class="hit"><img alt="" src=""></div>
```

Comment: Looks great, can I rely on this method? Also I have a follow up, is it possible to attach some sort of re-check method every, lets say 100ms, till all of them are not empty and stop this checking if number of attempts  = 100 and some of them or all are still empty @Zakaria Acharki

Comment: Yes that possible, could you please tell us how those divs are filled (by user/ by script )?

Comment: By jQuery .get() @Zakaria Acharki

Comment: Can you please add the max attempt number into you function, I will be really appreciate this @Zakaria Acharki

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a dom collection to [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to turn it into an array and you want to check if there are any children

```
function match(el) {return el.children.length;}
if (Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("hit")).every(match)) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nearly, you can loop through your array and check if each individual element has child elements.

```
var hitElements = document.getElementsByClassName("hit");

var allHaveContent = true;

for (i=0; i< hitElements.length; i++)
{
    if(!hitElements[i].hasChildNodes())
    {
        allHavecontent = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, can the same be done by checking innerHTML instead of childNodes, what of these two will be more reliable? @Sean T

Comment: Sure you can use innerHtml, that will detect content that is not a child element. e.g, `<div>Hello</div>`

Answer (score 0):

```js
if( ($('.hit').is(':empty'))) {


   console.log(" Some div are Empty.");
 

} else {
   console.log('All the divs are filled.');

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hit"><span id="t1"><p>Some text</p></span></div>
<div class="hit">Some text</div>
<div class="hit"><img alt="" src="">Some text</div>
```